# Webdriverio Illegal Capabilities IEDriver

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, webdriver-io, selenium-iedriver

Running webdriverio with the below configs results in the error:

`Illegal key values seen in w3c capabilities: [hostname, path, port, protocol]`

**Configs**

```
config = {
    runner: 'local',
    path: '/wd/hub',
    specs: [
        './e2e/spec/*.js'
    ],
    exclude: [],
    maxInstances: 1,
    capabilities: [{
    }],

    logLevel: 'error',
    bail: 0,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200',
    waitforTimeout: 10000,
    connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
    connectionRetryCount: 3,
    services: [
        ['selenium-standalone', {
            logPath: 'logs',
            installArgs: {
                drivers: {
                    ie: {
                        version: "3.141.0",
                        arch: "ia32", // forces use of 32 bit driver
                        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200'
                    }
                }
            },
            args: {
                drivers: {
                    ie: {
                        version: "3.141.0",
                        arch: "ia32", // forces use of 32 bit driver
                        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200'
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    ],
    framework: 'mocha',
    reporters: ['spec'],
    mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 300000
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the version of my `@wdio/selenium-standalone-service` was at 6 while the rest of my webdriverio packages were at version 5.